# Laravel deployment with capistrano cache files

Tags: laravel, caching, nginx, deployment, capistrano

I am having an issue while I'm trying to deploy a Laravel application onto an Ubuntu Server with Capistrano.

My deployment directory is /var/www/project_stage. When I deploy my project to that directory, everything works just fine. My project becomes live, every single line of code works just as it should.

But when I make a change and deploy a new version of same project, somehow (I'm guessing) my files are getting cached and not responding with the newest release, they are still responding as the old version that alredy being overwritten.

When I deploy the project to a different folder (etc: /var/www/project_stage2 instead of /var/www/project_stage) and change my Nginx config to serve from that folder, it works as it should again. But not in the second deploy to same directory. So I can say that I can deploy to a different directory every time, but I cannot deploy to same directory twice. It always responses as first deploy.

Here's what I've tried:

- I checked whether the current directory of Capistrano is linked to
  correct folder, which it has.
- I checked whether the changes I made are visible on new deploy, which
  they are. Files are absolutely changed on new deploy.
- I checked whether Nginx is looking for correct release directory, it
  has.
- I tried to run `php artisan cache:clear`, `route:clear`,
  `view:clear`, `config:cache` commands and I run `composer
  dump-autoload` too. Nothing worked.
- I changed Nginx's `sendfile` parameter to `off` and restarted, no
  result.
- I read a similar issue on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594173/laravel-deployment-cache-until-server-restart) question, but it didn't work on
  my case.

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
#deploy_path inherited from staging.rb

lock "~> 3.10.1"

set :application, "project_stage"
set :repo_url, "MY REPO HERE"
set :keep_releases, 10

set :laravel_dotenv_file, "./.env.staging"

namespace :deploy do


    before :updated, :easy do
        on roles(:all) do |host|


            execute :chmod, "-R 777 #{deploy_path}/shared/storage/logs"
            execute :chmod, "-R 777 #{deploy_path}/shared/storage/framework"

        end
    end





    after :finished, :hard do
        on roles(:all) do |host|

        end
    end 

    desc "Build"
    after :updated, :build do
        on roles(:web) do
            within release_path  do
                execute :php, "artisan clear-compiled"
                execute :php, "artisan cache:clear"
                execute :php, "artisan view:clear"
                execute :php, "artisan route:cache"
                execute :php, "artisan config:cache"
            end
        end
    end


end #end deploy namespace
```

I am using PHP7.0 (FPM with unix socket), Nginx, Laravel5, Capistrano3 (with capsitano/laravel gem), Ubuntu Server 16.4.

Comment: Are you using opcode cache with `opcache.validate_timestamps` set to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are describing could occur if you are using [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) with [`opcache.validate_timestamps`](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps) set to zero. With validate_timestamps set to zero, OPcache never checks for a newer version of the file. This improves performance slightly, but it means you will need to manually flush the cache.

There are two things you can do to resolve the issue:

1. Set opcache.validate_timestamps to 1 in your php.ini. This will result in a small performance decrease.
2. ...or flush the cache during your deployment, after the new files have been deployed, by calling [`opcache_reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php) in a PHP script.

Note that because you are using php-fpm, you should be able to flush the cache from the cli. If you were using Apache with mod_php you would need to flush the cache in a script invoked by Apache (through an HTTP request) rather than from the cli. The cache must be flushed in the context that your application runs in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked my php settings and saw that opcache.validate_timestamps are set to On. And opcache.enabled is On indeed. Should I set any of these to off?  By the way, I run opcache_reset(); manually from a script and BOOM, my commits are online. You spotted the problem sir! Thank you.

Comment: @EnesApaydın I would recommend leaving `opcache.enabled` on in production. Using opcache results in a significant performance increase.